# How to hand duplicate duplicate values in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the following data frame with several duplicates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID': [4562, 4562], 
        'city': ['Monroe', 'Montgomery'], 
        2005: [144, np.NaN], 
        2006: [173,  np.NaN], 
        2007: [145, np.NaN], 
        2008: [145, np.NaN], 
        2009: [np.NaN, 211], 
        2010: [np.NaN, 273]
    }
)

print(df)
     ID        city   2005   2006   2007   2008   2009   2010
0  4562      Monroe  144.0  173.0  145.0  145.0    NaN    NaN
1  4562  Montgomery    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  211.0  273.0
```

The city name changed over the years, thus the duplicate rows for the same ID but different city name. How do I do the following:

1. take the values for Monroe, 2005 - 2008 and replace the NaN for Montgomery,
2. drop the Monroe row?

Comment: `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg('last')`  @YOBEN_S is correct.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').last()
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Dataframe.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method in combination with [`last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html). You can find the solution below.

```
>>> df.groupby('ID', as_index=False, sort=False).last()
     ID        city   2005   2006   2007   2008   2009   2010
0  4562  Montgomery  144.0  173.0  145.0  145.0  211.0  273.0
```